# Swift How to DRY code in variable closures?

Tags: ios, swift, dry

I am using Auto Layout (programmatically) to set up my ViewController, I've gotten everything I wanted, but now I want to make my code more efficient and I notice I have quite a handful of repeating code, I'm trying to figure out how to take repeating code in a variable closure and put it else where so the code is cleaner.

How do I go about cleaning up my code? Still new to variable closures.

The code that I've copy and pasted is a global variable.

```
let descriptionTextViewOne: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()

    let text = "Tap anywhere to start\nyour day right!"
    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.white
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.init(name: "Marker felt", size: 25)!,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.init(red: 91.0/255.0, green: 91.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        .shadow: shadow
    ]
    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.isSelectable = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    return textView
}()

let descriptionTextViewTwo: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()

    let text = "A happy video a day\nmakes the heartache\ngo away."
    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.white
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.init(name: "Marker felt", size: 25)!,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.init(red: 91.0/255.0, green: 91.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        .shadow: shadow
    ]
    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.isSelectable = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    return textView
}()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Dry Code* ?

Comment: "Don't Repeat Yourself"

I have code in both variable closures that are repeating each other and I am trying to figure out how to condense repeating code in another block.

Comment: "Everyday you learn something new" - I jumped to this question by reading "DRY" code. :) Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function and reuse it

```
func descriptionTextView(with text: String) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.white
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.init(name: "Marker felt", size: 25)!,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.init(red: 91.0/255.0, green: 91.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        .shadow: shadow
    ]
    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.isSelectable = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    return textView
}

lazy var descriptionTextViewOne: UITextView = descriptionTextView(with: "Tap anywhere to start\nyour day right!")

lazy var descriptionTextViewTwo: UITextView = descriptionTextView(with: "A happy video a day\nmakes the heartache\ngo away.")
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'm trying to do this at the moment, would you be able to elaborate on the separate class method and lazy var? Thank you!

Comment: @Sherman I fixed from `let` to `lazy var` for support in case on the top level of a class

Comment: thanks! This worked! I also made it a private func. thanks a bunch.

Comment: Perhaps we can combine these two lines to one line? - `let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    textView.attributedText = attributedText` to `textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)`